# Oracle VPD how to reference the table

Tags: sql, oracle, row-level-security

I'm struggling with the following problem. I want to restrict access to a table using Oracle VPD. In the where clause that the select policy function returns I need a reference to the table in a subquery as follows:

```
select * from Table t1
where not exists (select 1 from Table t2 where t2.name=t1.name and t2.date=t1.date)
```

(The example doesn't make a lot of sense except to illustrate the problem)

I have no control over the select part of the query.

```
select * from Table t1
```

The table can be given any alias or none at all. So therefore I have no idea how to reference the table in the where clause. 
Is there a way to get around this?

(Oracle 10GR2)

Comment: OK, thanks to Tony I got my solution. where (name,date) not in (select name,date ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to use NOT IN:

```
(name, datecol) not in (select name, datecol from table2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround but I have two columns to compare. I'll update my example accordingly

Comment: Thanks sometimes the solution is staring you in the face... but that's why there is Stackoverlflow